# Git to many remotes

Tags: git

If I run

```
$ git branch -a
```

I get

```
* develop
  remotes/composer/compliance
  remotes/composer/develop
  remotes/composer/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/compliance
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

How can I remove all `remotes/composer`?
I just want to keep

```
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
  remotes/origin/compliance
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the second remote (and not see its branches) then do:

```
git remote rm composer
```

This won't "delete" anything, but you will stop seeing all the branches on the remote "composer"